# Corrupt playlists missing some newlines, how do I add them?

Tags: bash, newline, playlist

The problem I have is that some big playlists of mine contain some lines that are missing a newline.

What I want to do is parse the file and insert `\n` before `/run/` if there is no new line.  I tried:

```
text=$(< *.m3u)
text=${text//$'/run/}'/$'\n\n\r/run/}'}
printf "%s\n" "$text" > file.m3u
```

but it doesn't appear to work.  I have tried some other approaches but they all fail, so I'm thinking perhaps I am missing something very obvious and basic.

OK line:

```
/run/.../../.. .../hippho.mp3
```

Defective line:

```
/run/.../../.. .../holla.amigo.mp3/run/.../../.. .../dodoh.mp3
```

In response to the first reply, this

```
sed -e 's@/run/@\n/run/@g' *.m3u > PLAYLIST
```

gives me a file with many `\n\n/run/`.  I tried to fix it with

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\n/\n/g;p' PLAYLIST > PLAYLIST1
```

which removes them, but instead lists all files twice -- why is that?

My fix to remove the second listing of the files:

```
playlist='PLAYLIST1'
split -a 1 -d -n l/2 $playlist $playlist
cp PLAYLIST10 PLAYLIST
```

This finally gives me what I want, but there must be prettier ways.

there was.
    sed -e 's@(.)/run/@\1\n/run/@g' *.m3u 
does it all thanks tripleee

Comment: I see you are concatenating all your m3u files. Perhaps some of those files don't end with a newline?

Comment: well no,  every folder I run the script in only has one m3u file, that's way *.m3u

Answer (score 1):

This uses sed, not bash, and does add a new line at beginning of file.

```
sed -e 's@/run/@\n/run/@g' *.m3u
```

Comment: that adds \n before all /run/ so got a lot of \n\n/run/ now in my files

Comment: Try `sed -e 's@\(.\)/run/@\1\n/run/@g' *.m3u` instead; change the `-e` to an `-i` once you are satisfied that it does what you want.

Comment: Or `sed -e 's@/run/@\n/run/@g; s/^\n//'`

Comment: sed -e 's@\(.\)/run/@\1\n/run/@g' *.m3u does it thanks tripleee

Comment: no if you just "formulated" it as an answer, instead of a comment, you could get the cred triplee